# How to import $sce - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I would like to start using `$sce` what means **Strict Contextual Escaping**, for explicitly trusting HTML.

I have tried to use `DOMSanitizer` to sterilize the Stirng but it seems to not work.

```
**format-xml.pipe.ts**

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import { escape } from 'querystring';
import { TestExecutionComponent } from './test-execution/test-execution.component';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'formatXml'
})
export class FormatXmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }

  testExecutionComponent: TestExecutionComponent;

  transform(xml: String): SafeHtml {
    var formatted = '';
    var reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
    xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\r\n$2$3');
    var pad = 0;
    jQuery.each(xml.split('\r\n'), function (index, node) {
      var indent = 0;
      if (node.match(/.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/)) {
        indent = 0;
      } else if (node.match(/^<\/\w/)) {
        if (pad != 0) {
          pad -= 1;
        }
      } else if (node.match(/^<\w[^>]*[^\/]>.*$/)) {
        indent = 1;
      } else {
        indent = 0;
      }

      var padding = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < pad; i++) {
        padding += '  ';
      }

      formatted += padding + node + '\r\n';
      pad += indent;
    });

    var escaped = formatted.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '<').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;').replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
    let safeEscaped = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(escaped);
    console.log(safeEscaped)
    return safeEscaped;
  }
}
```

but it did not work.

After it I read that it is also possible to work with `$sce`

I would like to call to a pipe with the proper string (same pipe than before) to use the `$sce.trustAsHtml`.

As far as I know `$sce` is a service used by Angular but it seems that I need to import it first. How could I do it?

I do not mind about finding a way to do it using `Explicitly Trusting` with `$sce`

Comment: add `angular-sanitize` script (CDN), inject `ngSanitize` into your module and inject `$sce` into your controller/service

Comment: the same way you inject any module, syntax depends if you are in a controller, directive or anything, and how you chose to inject

Comment: that looks like Angular 2/4/5, not AngularJS, you should change the tag or specify the version used

Comment: yeah, you tagged wrong. Let my add the answer for `angular2` also

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer For angular1:**

First you need to add `angular sanitize` on which `$sce` depends.

you can add that by,

`<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-sanitize.js"></script>`

Then add it to app module as dependency,

**`angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])`**

**In controller:**

You can import `$sce` via **`dependency injection`** **in your controller**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$sce',
  function AppController($scope, $sce) {
     $scope.myFunction(){
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        test[i] = $sce.trustAsHtml(main.links[i]);
      }
     }
  }]);
```

[**Here is a plunker example generated from Official docs**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0QMWQl9r2JArspbsHupy?p=preview)

---

**Answer For angular2+:**

As you mentioned you should can use `Dom Sanitizer` using a pipe

- **Angulars DOM sanitizer explicitly marks html as trusted**

**Pipe:**

```
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(style) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div [innerHTML]="myVal | safeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: `ngSanitize` dependency for $sce has been removed in latest versions of `angularjs`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, I think I heard that wrong, so adding `sanitize`

Comment: This code works. Actually my code was also working the problem is that I have no idea why is it not introducing the "\n". Do you know why my old pipe could not be introducing "\n"